# Can't activate Windows 10 Pro with license linked to Microsoft account or product key

Tags: windows-10, license, windows-activation, product-key

I'm trying to activate a new Windows installation using the digital license that's associated with my Microsoft account. On the old (activated) pc, I can go to the activation setting and see the "Windows is activated with a digital license tied to your Microsoft account" message.

On the new PC, if I log in with the same Microsoft account, Windows is not activated. I get the message that a valid product key has not been found (0xC004F213).

Using the trouble shooter, I get the message that Windows cannot be activated on this device. I then click "I recently changed the hardware for this device."

I then get a dialog showing me the device with the old motherboard. If I click "Activate", I get a simple "Windows cannot be activated" message.

If I go back to settings and try to change the product key, and enter the old pc's product key, I get an error that says the key is invalid (0x80041023).

I'm kind of at a loss now. How do I get this working?

Windows 10 Pro x64 was installed on both devices using the same USB drive.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate if the license was a retail or OEM license

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows 10 serial is associated with the old hardware.
It is registered with your Microsoft account, but that is only for the purpose
of easily activating the old hardware.

Microsoft takes into account too many parameters of your old hardware,
you cannot trick it into activating the new hardware with a serial that
was already used.

The old activation key was apparently an OEM license that came with the old
hardware, maybe it was even burnt into the BIOS.
It cannot have been a Retail version, because Retail keys are transferable.

So, sorry, you need to buy a Windows 10 serial for your new computer.

Comment: Not entirely true. In Germany (and probably the whole EU) even OEM licenses are legally transferable.

Comment: @TJJ: Interesting. Can you show some proof that this works?

Comment: I can show you the court rulings. However, as you can see, Microsoft sometimes needs to be reminded of their obligations.